# Can't read bytes or lines from a GPS device that other applications are able to

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, gps, serial-port

I have a vb.net application that is able to read gps info from gps connected to usb. This works on about 50-60 different computers and gps devices, however there is one gps device (did try it on several computers aswell) that this will not work on.

I did think there might be something wrong with the gps device, but there are two other applications (Haicom Viewer and a custom application I do not have the source code for) that works with that device without any issues. So there has to be something with my application that is not able to work with that specific device.

Currently I'm using a SerialPort control and when using Read() I get "blank" bytes and ReadLine() times out.

I have tried different BaudRates, Encodings and Hanshakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by setting DtrEnable = True on the SerialPort control. However I do not know why that was the deciding factor. If anyone could explain why only 1 of many GPS devices needed this to be true it would be much appreciated.